# How do I scrape a single google sheets cell value to my website as a variable without any Oauth verification? (I am using repl.it)

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have an Infographic on my website that updates automatically depending on the data on my google sheet(single range not all over the place) . I would like to have each of the cells coming in as variables so I can put them wherever I want within the Geochart(Infographic) element written with javascript.

Comment: You can check Google sheets API.  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Comment: When I do that it prints into my website console, but I cannot call it(it is not a variable in my code). Any Idea how to call it in my code?